# Mono for Android / MonoTouch: Mono Version

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I searched around but I could find an answer.

Is there anywhere I can see which exact version of Mono is running underneath a particular MonoTouch / Mono for Android version?

For example, my 'About Visual Studio' window shows I have Mono For Android 1.0.1.10323

How can I find out the corresponding Mono version being used 'under the hood'?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MonoTouch and Mono for Android are built on separate branches from Mono itself. Those branches also includes some product specific changes / fixes. This means an *exact* match is not possible - but I can tell you a *general* match:

Recent releases (e.g. MonoTouch 4.x and 5.x) are based on Mono 2.10, while MonoTouch 3.x was based on Mono 2.6.

Mono for Android is based on Mono 2.10 (at least all versions released by Xamarin).